CSS Problem I can't get it to look right on mobile
I have a problem where everything looks fine on my computer, but on the mobile phone, it's terrible. The fields are causing the most trouble; I can't seem to get them to stack one below the other on the mobile. Can anyone help me?
Here are images of what happens on Desktop GOOD, Phone, Phone 2, Phone 3.
/* Body styling */
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Styling for container */
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; /* Added to vertically center the content */
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/* Styling for calculator container */
.calculator-container {
    width:794px;
    transform:translatex(835px) translatey(192px);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Styling for summary tab */
.summary-tab {
    width:820px;
    transform:translatex(823px) translatey(203px);
    height:310px;
    line-height:9.4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}



h1 {
    color: #333;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #555;
}

select, input {
    margin: 5px 0 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

#totalPrice {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

#dimensions {
    height:127px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#heightLabel {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #dimensions {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}

/* Styling for color options */
.color-options {
    column-gap: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    row-gap: 10px;
}

/* Styling for individual color option */
.color-options input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.color-options label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styling for selected color option */
.color-options input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Label */
.calculator-container label{
    text-align:left;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:21px;
}

/* Styling for file upload */
#fileSection {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#fileNameDisplay {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #555;
}

/* Background image styling */
body {
    background-image: url("bcg.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

/* Styling for summary tab */
.summary-tab {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Added margin-bottom to create space between summary and next element */
}

.summary-tab h4 {
    color: #333;
}

.summary-tab div {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 18px; /* Adjust the font size to match your design */
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

/* Styling for motor options */
#motorSection {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.motor-options {
    column-gap: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    row-gap: 10px;
}

.motor-options input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.motor-options label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.motor-options input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#totalSummary p.empty-option {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
}

/* Styling for other options */
.material-options {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align:left;
}

.material-options input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.material-options label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.material-options label::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-options input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
}

/* Styling for email form container */
#emailFormContainer {
    display: none; /* Initially hide the email form container */
}


/* Dropdown Meni */
#itemDropdown{
 width:277px;
 position:relative;
 left:-257px;
 background-color:#f3f5f5;
}

/* Za Duzinu text */
.duzina label {
 position:relative;
 top:-94px;
 left:366px;
}

/* Za Duzinu */
.duzina input[type="number"] {
width: 277px;
 position:relative;
 top:-94px;
left:103px;;
background-color:#f3f5f5;
}


/* Za Visinu text */
.visina label {
 position:relative;
 left:366px;
 top:-143px;
}

/* Za Visinu */
.visina input[type="number"] {
width: 277px;
 position:relative;
 left:-8px;
 top:20px;
 background-color:#f3f5f5;

}


/* Za Sirinu text */
.sirina label {
 position:relative;
 top:-53px;
}

/* Za Sirinu */
.sirina input[type="number"] {
width: 277px;
 position:relative;
 left:-257px;
 top:-49px;
 background-color:#f3f5f5;

}

/* Kalendar */
#datepickerSection {
    display: none; /* Hide the date picker section by default */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

.datum-text {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #555; /* Adjust the color as needed */
}

.datepicker {
    background-color:#f3f5f5;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 277px;
    position:relative;
    left:-257px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Za upload formu*/
.upload {
width: 277px;
position:relative;
left:-318px;
width:123px;
}


/* Upload buton */
.upload {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: #007bff; /* Change the background color as needed */
    color: #fff; /* Change the text color as needed */
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Upload kad se prelazi misem*/
.upload:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3; /* Change the background color on hover */
}



/* Za text ime slike */
#fileNameDisplay {
 position:relative;
 left:-200px;
 color:#ee4390;
}


/* Greska odabrani fajl nije slika   staviti tamo funkciju da direktno iz css ubacuje odavde */
.error-text1 {
    color: red;
}


/* X dugme otkaze upload slike */
.cancel-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 5px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

I've tried everything, expecting these fields to be stacked one below the other in order as they should. I've Tried:
@media all and (min-width:960px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:801px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
}  

    not working


Welcome to StackOverflow! May I suggest that you edit your question by trimming down the CSS to just the relevant styles and adding the relevant section of HTML as well for a narrower context.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your use of position: relative with each of the input fields is in direct conflict with the flex styles and media queries that are failing to apply. Relative position leaves a gap behind at the element's origin and positions the element to stay at whatever position you offset it to, so it isn't friendly with these responsive properties that you're trying to use.
Remove the position property (and clear the now-useless top, bottom, left, or right styles) from your form elements and then I recommend experimenting with flex box from a mobile perspective first. From there you can use media queries to make the desktop layout look good.
